# SQL WHERE (contains or equal)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to take the first row (postgresql 9.2) :

```
SELECT posts.employee_id, posts.month, posts.year
  FROM posts
WHERE  ((posts.month = 9 AND posts.year = 2013) 
        OR 
        (posts.month IS NULL AND posts.year IS NULL))
ORDER BY posts.employee_id
```

But it returns: 
[image: Execution of the query] 
**The goal is to get result in just one row for each employee_id**:

IF month and year have found 
THEN return the first record with the month and year 
ELSE return the second record with month = NULL and YEAR = NULL 
There's should be just one row (not two as on picture) 
It will seems as a default fallback for non present records.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/32227/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure how `MAX` behaves in PostgreSQL but something like this would work in `SQL-server`:

```
SELECT 
  posts.employee_id, 
  max(posts.month) as "month", 
  max(posts.year) as "year"
FROM posts
WHERE 
 (posts.month = 9  AND posts.year  = 2013)  
 OR 
 (posts.month IS NULL AND posts.year  IS NULL)
GROUP BY posts.employee_id
```

This assumes that only one or two records will be returned for each id.

---

**EDIT** (Updated Fiddle)

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47647/20)**

Comment: It rules, I gonna check it on real db dump. Will see result. Also thx for sql-fiddle.

Comment: Regarding your SQLFiddle: you can't do a variable assignment `month = max(posts.month)` inside a SELECT statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47647/18

Comment: Just changed the fiddle couple of syntax errors on my part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... amended now. Although this is still a workaround: row_number is the best way of doing this - not sure how to write that in this dialect.

Comment: `row_number()` works the same in Postgres as it does in SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually just re-read the OP and not too sure of exact requirement - what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT posts.employee_id, posts.month, posts.year
FROM posts
WHERE posts.employee_id = 1
AND (posts.month = 9  AND posts.year  = 2013)  
OR (posts.month IS NULL AND posts.year  IS NULL)
ORDER BY month DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1
```

[**From Documentation**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-order.html)

> The NULLS FIRST and NULLS LAST options can be used to determine
>   whether nulls appear before or after non-null values in the sort
>   ordering. By default, null values sort as if larger than any non-null
>   value; that is, NULLS FIRST is the default for DESC order, and NULLS
>   LAST otherwise.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47647/4)

Comment: This is by far the better solution.

Comment: I've edited my issue with your solution. But it returns all employee_ids instead

Comment: `SELECT posts.employee_id, posts.month, posts.year
               FROM posts
               WHERE posts.employee_id = 1
               AND ( (posts.month = 9  AND posts.year  = 2013)  
               OR (posts.month IS NULL AND posts.year  IS NULL))` try wrapping the AND with wrapping ()

Comment: @itsnikolay whats the problem you see in the posted solution ?

Comment: If I do it without `posts.employee_id = 1` then `LIMIT 1` does not help there.

Comment: Check the fiddle demo link .. what do you want to return when employee_id is not specified ?

Answer (score 0):

You can order your results and put limit 1 at the end of your query. Do you have some definition of what is the first record?

Comment: I think `LIMIT 1` is not a persistent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can model rownum like this in postgresql;

Postgresql > 8.4

```
 SELECT 
     row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS i, 
     e.col1, 
     e.col2, 
     ... 
    FROM ...
```